# clear ID Properties completely

Tags: properties

I want to add some custom properties to a bone by an if statement

```
if len(bpy.data.armatures[armSearch].bones[boneSearch].items()) > 1:                    
    itemCount = len(bpy.data.armatures[armSearch].bones[boneSearch].items()) + 1                                
    bpy.data.armatures[armSearch].bones[boneSearch]["skName"+str(itemCount)] = shapeKeySearch                     

elif len(bpy.data.armatures[armSearch].bones[boneSearch].items()) == 1:                    
    bpy.data.armatures[armSearch].bones[boneSearch]["skName"] = shapeKeySearch

else:
    bpy.data.armatures[armSearch].pose.bones[boneSearch]["skName"] = shapeKeySearch
```

But when I look for the ID properties in the console there are already tow of them even though I deleted them. How can I delete them completely ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delete custom ID property by:

```
del pose_bone["ID_prop_name"]
```

Comment: But why are they not shown ?